# Problem displaying data in gridview with object data source (L2S)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have a gridview using object datasource for data binding. Everything is working fine except, When i add some new records to data it is not displaying immediately, it requires a refresh. I am using L2S Business Object with Object Data Source. Same thing in update and delete events.

Comment: Can you post your code of the update or delete events, also are you using an UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you re-binding your GridView after making the changes to your data?

Comment: I tried but nothing happend. Even i tried to call DataBind() of object datasource

Comment: @Bumble Without seeing code, it's hard to provide any additional insight

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss EditIndex property, change it on every event, like :

```
 protected void HlnkbInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ...
     gv.EditIndex = -1;
     DataBindGV();

 }

protected void gv_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
     ...
     gv.EditIndex = -1;
     DataBindGV();
}

 protected void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {
     ...
     gv.EditIndex = -1;
     DataBindGV();
}

protected void gv_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
     ...
     gv.EditIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
     DataBindGV();
}
```